# How to test EventMachine.next_tick with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, eventmachine

I'm trying to write rspec tests to test a method something like this:

```
def poll_registrations
  redis.blpop('new', 0).callback do |id|
    add_id(id)
  end
  EventMachine.next_tick {
    poll_registrations
  }
end
```

I'm fine with most of it, but I can't work out how to ensure that it will continue to call itself every `next_tick`. I'm getting tangled up in `and_yield`s etc and getting nowhere.

Comment: Using next_tick is bad idea. It will peg your cpu.  If you can describe your use case, we might be able to suggest a better implementation.

Comment: @CodeGroover `next_tick` just schedules the block to be run on the next iteration of the event loop, not every iteration of the event loop.

Comment: @tadman this recursive has the same idea like "while true: poll_registrations; end" isn't it?

Comment: @CodeGroover No, it runs only once at the next available opportunity. You're thinking of the [Timer](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/Timer.html) object.

Comment: @tadman i need to play to check this :)

Comment: I agree with @CodeGroover, `next_tick` seems like the wrong implementation, based on the code sample. Using `EM.add_timer(0.1) {…}` would be easier to test and keep the logic of polling registrations separated from the process of queuing the polling. As it stands you cannot poll registrations without triggering `next_tick`, which means you cannot call this method from outside the EM loop (e.g., from IRB).

Comment: As you're using redis, this could be achieved be registering with redis pub/sub queues, and remove the need to manually poll redis altogether?